# Azure CDN - Invalid characters when add content-types

Tags: azure, gzip, content-type, azure-cdn

From the documentation:

> The text field can contain a comma-separated list of content-types that should be enabled for compression via http Accept-Encoding/Content-Encoding.

On the [Troubleshoot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-troubleshoot-compression/#) page - there is even screenshot with content-types added.

But when I'm trying to add new types (`image/jpeg`, `application/javascript`) - I have an error:

> "Invalid characters. Characters allowed are alphanumeric, -, +, . and
>   /."

What I'm doing wrong here?

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space following each comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
text/plain,text/html,text/css,application/x-javascript,text/javascript,text/xml,application/vnd.ms-fontobject,application/javascript,application/json,application/x-font-opentype,application/x-font-truetype,application/x-font-ttf,application/xml,font/eot,font/opentype,font/otf,image/svg+xml
```

If you need all of them, keep in mind there must not be spaces anywere I know Azure